# Suppress MsgBoxes on launching Access OR Prevent form opening on launch?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

To preface this, I messed up.

I have a function that runs for each item in the database, to compare against a given value. I added a MsgBox to the code in order to check values for debugging. This function runs when the default form for the project (the one that loads when I launch Access) loads-- on *every record in the database*. Currently, that's slightly over 13000 items.

Is there any way to suppress the messages, launch the project without loading that form, or edit VBA from the project without launching the project?

EDIT: I've just realized that I can press ESCAPE during a MsgBox display to abort the query. Problem solved.

Comment: Noticing the edit.. Is your question now answered?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am not sure what the proper etiquette in this situation (figuring out the answer to your own question some time after posting) is.

Comment: You can just post your solution as an answer. Try to be thorough, though.